# Linq to XML select node from config.xml (Lambda expression or classic query)

Tags: c#, xml, linq, lambda

I am using .net 4.0 winforms. In my application a have config file (config.xml), on this file i have lots nodes and child nodes, all are different, i want to select specific node and nodes inside the selected node.

I tried lots of solutions but not succeed.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: you could load the xml using a `XDocument` and the call the appropriate method on the object.

Comment: Hi can you give me more explanation with sample please.

Comment: @user3066993 - Which specific tag value you are looking for inside `maintenance_anomalies` tag?

Comment: <nom_operation> and then all <statut>.

Answer (score 2):

This should give you the correct result:-

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"XMLFilePath");
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Silvio.Settings";
var result = doc.Root.Element(ns + "maintenance_anomalies")
             .Descendants(ns + "nom_operation")
             .Select(x =>
                        new
                           {
                              NomOperation = (string)x,
                              statutList = x.Parent.Element(ns + "statuts")
                                                   .Elements(ns + "statut")
                                                   .Select(z => (string)z).ToList()
                           }).ToList();
```

**Approach:**

From the Xdocument object select the root node which is `Main`. From this select the Element `maintenance_anomalies` by including the Namespace associated with it. From there you can select all the descendants of `nom_operation` and fetch it's value. To find all `statut` inside `nom_operation` go back to parent node which is `operation` and from there select all  `statut` elements.

You can also project a Type instead of anonymous type.

Getting following output:-

[image]

Comment: @user3066993 - It's the namespace associated with your XML. Updated.

Comment: Good explanation. Thank you very much. Works fine.

Comment: @user3066993 - You're Welcome :) You can accept the answer if that helped you. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

I had a couple of issues with your xml.  First there is an invalid character so instead of using the Load method.  There is also a namespace issue so I used Where method to get the tag maintenance_anomalies.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication53
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string file = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(file);
            XElement maintenance_anomalies = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "maintenance_anomalies").FirstOrDefault();
            XNamespace ns = maintenance_anomalies.Name.Namespace;

            var results = maintenance_anomalies.Elements(ns + "operation").Select(x => new{
                nom_operation = x.Element(ns + "nom_operation").Value,
                statut = string.Join(",",x.Descendants(ns + "statut").Select(y => y.Value).ToArray())
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, So far so good ? Then how can i select the child node inside the <maintenance_anomalies> node.

Comment: <nom_operation> and then all <statut>.

Comment: Update with latest request.

Comment: Thank you very much. Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The line below should let u access the node u requested. Use this is your class `using System.Xml;`

```
 XmlDocument XmlDocObj = new XmlDocument();
 XmlNode UserNameNode = XmlDocObj.SelectSingleNode("maintenance_anomalies");
```

Comment: Hi can you give me more explanation with sample please.

Comment: @user3066993 The XmlDocument allows you to read through the Xml document, where as the .SelectSingleNode selects the node you want to access.